# Python Multiprocessing Manager Error-‘ForkAwareLocal’ object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I wrote the following code using the `multiprocessing` module to execute two processes in parallel. One requirement is to access a shared Queue in the multiprocessing module used to store data by one process and read from it by another process. I tried to write it using the code below, I got this. Any help, please?

```
/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/adhamenaya/DataspellProjects/MultiProcessing/multi-processing.py 
Producer process started...
Consumer process started...
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 810, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/DataspellProjects/MultiProcessing/multi-processing.py", line 36, in run
    data = self.queue.get_nowait()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_nowait
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 814, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 801, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 630, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 810, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/DataspellProjects/MultiProcessing/multi-processing.py", line 22, in run
    self.queue.put_nowait(input_data)
  File "<string>", line 2, in put_nowait
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 814, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 801, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/Users/adhamenaya/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 630, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My code:

```
import time
import random
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool


# consumer class simulates the continuous data collection process
class Producer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print("Producer process started...")
        while True:
            # simulate the time needed to collect data
            input_time = random.randrange(1, 4)
            time.sleep(input_time)

            # simulate date collection
            input_data = random.randrange(5, 10)
            self.queue.put_nowait(input_data)
            print(f" {input_data} is collected in time {input_time} secs")


# producer class simulates the work of data processing algorithm
class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        process_data = 0
        print("Consumer process started...")
        while True:
            data = self.queue.get_nowait()
            # simulate time needed to process data
            procss_time = random.randrange(6, 9)
            time.sleep(procss_time)

            # Simulate data processing algorithm
            process_data += data
            print(f" input: {data}, new result: {process_data} is processed in {procss_time} secs")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a shared queue

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()

    producer = Producer(queue)
    consumer = Consumer(queue)

    # start instances on parallel processes
    producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.run).start()
    consumer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer.run).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues.

1. You have a race condition in that your consumer is issuing a non-blocking `get` call on the queue but it is certainly possible for the queue to be empty in which case a `queue.Empty` exception will be raised. You need to use a *blocking* `get`.
2. You are using a *managed* queue which is implemented by creating a new process (done by the call to `multiprocessing.Manager()`) in which resides a `threading.Queue`. Method calls on the queue *proxy* created with `mamanger.Queue()` result in messages being sent to this process where the queue is actually updated. However, when your main thread that created this manager process ends, the manager process also ends and that is why you get the error you do. You need to prevent the main thread from terminating and the most straightforward way of doing this is to issue `join` calls on the processes you created. But note that your statement `producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.run).start()` does *not* assign to `producer_process` a `Process` instance; it assigns the return value from calling the `run` method.

So if you wish to continue to use a *managed queue*, which is less efficient than using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, you need:

```py
import time
import random
import multiprocessing


# consumer class simulates the continuous data collection process
class Producer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print("Producer process started...")
        while True:
            # simulate the time needed to collect data
            input_time = random.randrange(1, 4)
            time.sleep(input_time)

            # simulate date collection
            input_data = random.randrange(5, 10)
            self.queue.put_nowait(input_data)
            print(f" {input_data} is collected in time {input_time} secs")


# producer class simulates the work of data processing algorithm
class Consumer:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        process_data = 0
        print("Consumer process started...")
        while True:
            # Issue a blocking get:
            #data = self.queue.get_nowait()
            data = self.queue.get()
            # simulate time needed to process data
            procss_time = random.randrange(6, 9)
            time.sleep(procss_time)

            # Simulate data processing algorithm
            process_data += data
            print(f" input: {data}, new result: {process_data} is processed in {procss_time} secs")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a shared queue

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()

    producer = Producer(queue)
    consumer = Consumer(queue)

    # start instances on parallel processes
    producer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.run)
    consumer_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer.run)
    producer_process.start()
    consumer_process.start()
    # Prevent the main thread from terminating:
    producer_process.join()
    consumer_process.join()
```

But it would be more efficient to use a `multiprocessing.Queue`, in which case you also do not care whether the main thread terminates:

```py
... # code not shown since it has not changed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    producer = Producer(queue)
    consumer = Consumer(queue)

    # start instances on parallel processes
    multiprocessing.Process(target=producer.run).start()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=consumer.run).start()
```

**Now all you need to worry about is whether the producer can be producing queue items more quickly on the average than the consumer can process them in which case the queue will continuously grows in size. If that is a possibility, you may wish to start multiple consumers.**